# How to delete all pages products in form admin

Tags: magento2

I have 20k products. And I want to remove all the products via bulk operation in magento admin. But it's only delete the current page products only. Not all of. Can you guys please help us to delete all of them?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Magento gives 2 options, "Select All" and "Select visible on this page" if you Opt. "Select All" it will select all products.

Answer (score 0):

First run this query to delete all products

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`;
```

then run below query to start product id from 1

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

and then create product. Id will be start from 1

Comment: How can i delete it from magento admin as all products?

Comment: We can not delete product from Magento Admin more than 999 at once.

Comment: You need to do some customization for this.

Comment: This are the Reference Link for Customization - https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-delete-all-products/

Comment: Ok, But it is not allow me to delete as 999. I can delete only per page 100. Do you know why?

Comment: But in Default Magento you are able to delete 999 record at once. also check http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20191204-uqqk-41kb Screen. Maybe There is some problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> **See This Image :-**

[image]

```
Click On Select All On This Page And Delete All Products
```